# Listing all opened documents across all open visible apps in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I've come across doing something like:

**Code**:

```
tell application "Preview"
    set p to {}
    set p to documents
end tell
```

**Output**:

```
{document "1st.pdf" of application "Preview", document "2nd.pdf" of application "Preview"}
```

But this is highly app-specific—doing this on MS Word, for instance, yielded pathnames and some apps like CodeRunner don't understand the `documents` keyword at all.

Given these open documents:

```
Current open documents from all open visible apps
+– Microsoft Word.app
|  +– 1.docx
|  +– 2.docx
+– CodeRunner.app
|  +– 1.sh
|  +– 2.py
|  +– 3.pl
+– Preview.app
   +– 1.pdf
   +– 2.png
.
.
.
```

I want an output of something like this:

```
{"~/Documents/1.docx", "~/Downloads/2.docx", "~/Dropbox/folder/1.sh", "~/Dropbox/others/2.py", "~/Downloads/folder/folder/3.pl", "~/Documents/special/1.pdf", "~/Dropbox/special/2.png", ...}
```

How is it possible to list all open documents across all open apps?

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been trying to do this myself. I have concluded that there is no standard, guaranteed way to get the open documents of a running application.

What you tried is the best method. For apps that use the Cocoa document architecture (the majority), there is automatic AppleScript support for getting all the open `NSDocument` objects and querying certain properties of those objects. The mapping between the AppleScript properties and the Objective-C properties is shown below.

AppleScript property => Objective-C getter:

- `path` => `fileName`
- `modified` => `isDocumentEdited`
- `name` => `lastComponentOfFileName`

What you want is the `path` property. Like `tell application "Preview" to set documentsList to path of documents`.

Unfortunately, this automatic AppleScript support is only available for apps that use the Cocoa document architecture **and** have AppleScript enabled (via the `NSAppleScriptEnabled` Info.plist key). Therefore, this method will not work on some apps. For example, CodeRunner does not have AppleScript enabled. And TextMate does not use the Cocoa document architecture.